# Why webpack cannot resolve .css extension with same name in JSX?

Tags: webpack, import

**My webpack config**

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  }
}
```

**My files**

- App.jsx
- App.css

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App'

....
```

I thought webpack would know `App.css` without extension, but it wouldn't. But why?
Of course, `App.jsx` and `App.css` have same name. However, there is only one file named `App` outside of `App.jsx`.
Why this is happening? ( And I know the solution are adding extension or rename css file )

Comment: [If multiple files share the same name but have different extensions, webpack will resolve the one with the extension listed first in the array and skip the rest.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions)

Comment: @zero298 Thanks for the answer! I read docs, but I think I missed it.